# QTableWidget with relative-width, stretchable columns

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I'm trying to achieve a pyqt5 table similar to the following one:

[image]

First of all: I am not even sure that QTableWidget is the most appropiate widget, as I do not have much experience with Qt. QGridLayout could fit better. I tried it first but somehow I didn't know how to make it work to fit the requirements, any advice would be very much appreciated.

The table requirements are:

- Some cells contain text, some QCheckBoxes and some QRadioButtons
- The table width must always fill 100% of its parent's width as it resizes (I'm currently using `setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)`)
- The table should be vertically scrollable
- Some of its columns have a different relative width, and this relation must be kept (here start my problems)
- The centering of the columns is not the same for every one (couldn't find how to achieve this in the docs)

My current problem is that the use of `setSectionResizeMode` conflicts with `resizeSection`. I can have different column widths OR stretchable table width, but I don't know how to achieve both.

The example code looks like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHeaderView, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout
import sys

data = {'col1':['1','2','3','4'],
        'col2':['1','2','1','3'],
        'col3':['1','1','2','1']}


class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.table.setRowCount(4)
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.table.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        # self.table.horizontalHeader().resizeSection(1, 200) <-- no effect if stretch is activated

        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([colName for colName in data])
        self.fillTable()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


    def fillTable(self):
        for colNumber, colName in enumerate(data):
            for rowNumber, value in enumerate(data[colName]):
                self.table.setItem(rowNumber, colNumber, QTableWidgetItem(value))


if __name__=="__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Here's my other attempt, using a QGridLayout. The problem here is that the columns do not expand when the window is resized.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QGridLayout, QLabel, QPushButton, QApplication, QScrollArea, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        # Label
        self.label = QLabel('Test')

        # Grid
        self.grid = QWidget()
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.grid.setMinimumWidth(600) # Without this, the width relations are not kept

        # Grid elements
        for i in range(20):
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(QPushButton('A'), i, 0, 1, 1)
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(QPushButton('B'), i, 1, 1, 3)
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(QPushButton('C'), i, 4, 1, 1)

        # Scroll area
        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.grid)
        self.scrollArea.setMinimumWidth(self.grid.sizeHint().width())
        self.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        # Window layout
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    windowExample = MainWindow()
    windowExample.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Are you sure you really need a table? If you don't need the features of an item view, but only want a way to put labels and checkboxes/radios aligned, couldn't you use a plain QWidget with a QGridLayout set, inside a QScrollArea? (btw, QGridView doesn't exist anymore since Qt4). Should the columns be resizable? Could the table be resized? Should the "items" always occupy the whole available space? Have you considered to use [`setSectionResizeMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSectionResizeMode-1) for individual columns, instead of setting it for all the columns?

Comment: @musicamante Ok, that was a typo (I was refering to QGridLayout, not QGridView). GridLayout was my first attempt (find the example added in a new edition to my question), but I can't make the columns get resized when the window size changes. Yes, the columns should be resizable, and the grid or table should take all the width.

Comment: I'd suggest you to edit your post and provide your attempt at QGridLayout too, as it might be the more practical choice.

Comment: @musicamante That is what I just did.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the edit. I just posted an answer using the grid layout approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a grid layout is probably the best choice, as item views are better suited for showing item models and not to contain GUI elements.

What you're missing is the [`widgetResizable`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#widgetResizable-prop) property:

> If this property is set to false (the default), the scroll area honors the size of its widget.
>
> [...] If this property is set to true, the scroll area will automatically resize the widget in order to avoid scroll bars where they can be avoided, or to take advantage of extra space.

Then, you should not use the column span to ensure that widgets expand themselves, but [`setColumnStretch`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#setColumnStretch) instead.

Finally, to ensure that the scroll area always displays the contents without "cutting" the right side, you should not disable the horizontal scroll bar, but, instead, properly set the minimum width based on the contents of the area, the vertical scroll bar width and the scroll area frame width.

Consider that with all this you obviously don't need to set the grid minimum width anymore.

```
    # Grid elements
    for i in range(20):
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(QPushButton('A'), i, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(QPushButton('B'), i, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(QPushButton('C'), i, 2)
    # ensure that the second column uses a stretch factor bigger than the
    # default 0 value (which will only honor the size hints and policies of
    # each widget
    self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)

    # Scroll area
    self.scrollArea = QScrollArea()
    self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.grid)
    self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
    # compute the correct minimum width
    width = (self.grid.sizeHint().width() + 
        self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().sizeHint().width() + 
        self.scrollArea.frameWidth() * 2)
    self.scrollArea.setMinimumWidth(width)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see that now at least the content is not clipped and fills the parent's width. But two problems remain: first and third column are not expanding, but are fixed in width, and if I use setColumnStretch in all of them, then all are the same width. The second problem I see is that without grid.setMinimumWidth, at small window widths, the three columns also are set to equal widths.

Comment: Well, I can use setColumnStretch with different factors to keeep the column width ratio to solve the first problem.

Comment: Depending on the widgets, they will always get as small as they can, so if they are of same type and have similar contents, they will always become of the same minimum width. You can avoid that by setting a (possibly arbitrary) minimum width using [`setMinimumColumnWidth()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#setColumnMinimumWidth).